# Filter a dataFrame based on elemnt from a array column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with dataframe

```
       root
          |-- c: long (nullable = true)
          |-- data: array (nullable = true)
          |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
                  |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
                  |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm trying to filter this dataframe based on an element ["value1", "key1"] in the array data i.e if this element exist in data of df so keep it else delete it, I tried

```
df.filter(col("data").contain("["value1", "key1"])
```

but it didn't work. Also I tried to 
put `val f=Array("value1", "key1")` then `df.filter(col("data").contain(f))` it didn't work also.

Any help please?

Comment: note: usually, `array_contains` (from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`) is helpful for this, but in this case it wouldn't have helped, because it can only be applied to literals (e.g. `array_contains(data, "a")`) and not to structs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight forward approach would be to use a `udf` function as `udf` function helps to *perform logics row by row and in primitive datatypes* (thats what your requirement suggests to check every key and value of `struct` element in *array data column*)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//udf to check for key1 in key and value1 in value of every struct in the array field
def containsUdf = udf((data: Seq[Row])=> data.exists(row => row.getAs[String]("key") == "key1" && row.getAs[String]("value") == "value1"))
//calling the udf function in the filter 
val filteredDF = df.filter(containsUdf(col("data")))
```

so the `filteredDF` should be your desired output